# Can a collaborator install the Heroku Connect addon?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I am a collaborator in the app which I am working on. While I am trying to install Heroku connect I am getting an error: "that add-on plan is only available to select users". Do I need to be an owner of the app to install heroku connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this from the docs. It appears that you need to buy heroku connect addon in order to use it as no free plan available.

> Heroku Connect is currently GA, but does not have a free plan type.
>   Please contact your Heroku sales representative for information on
>   access and purchase or tell us about your project and a representative
>   will contact you. There is no self-service signup for Heroku Connect.

[Link to docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/herokuconnect)